# Accessing object property by assignment

Tags: objective-c

Say I have class like below

```
@interface Restaurant : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *restaurantID;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *restaurantName;
    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *restaurantAddress;

@end
```

If I am creating a "Restaurant" object say "rest" and and I can access the properties like rest.restaurantID and so on.

My question is, how can I access the properties if I am assigning objects.Something like this

```
Restaurant *rest = [[Restaurant alloc]init];
[rest setRestaurantName:@"MCD"]; 

id proxyObject;
proxyObject = rest;
```

How can I access property "restaurantName" using proxyObject instead of rest?

Thank you

Comment: Try to avoid this pattern. It will easily hurt you if you are not careful with casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the **id** dynamic type, you cannot access the property with the dotSyntax, you can however use the automaticly generated accessors methods.
if you have a @property called var, you can use the getter

```
- (id) var;
```

and the setter

```
- setVar:(id)var;
```

meaning in your case you can code like

```
[proxyObject setRestaurantId:@"anID"] // setter
NSString * restId = [proxyObject restaurantID]; //getter
```

and so on for each @property.

(look how the getter is EXACTLY the name of your property and how the setter name starts by set and then the name of your property starting by a capital letter)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in Objective-C, you could simply **cast** back the proxy object to a Restaurant instance :

```
id proxyObject;
proxyObject = rest;
[(Restaurant)proxyObject restaurantName];
```

or you could use **key/value** coding :

```
[proxyObject valueForKey:@"restaurantName"];
```

Another way could be declaring a protocol that declares the restaurant name and then implements that protocol in the restaurant class, after that you could use the instance of the protocol to call directly on it the getter `restaurantName` .